# How to format c drive and install ubuntu on it

Tags: system

I am a new in ubuntu, i wanna to install ubuntu in my windows os. I have 4 drive like as c, d, e and f. I wanna to install ubuntu on my c drive which override the windows 10 that's mean formatting c drive and install ubuntu on c drive without effecting other drive because i have no backup my other drives.

Comment: Always backup, unless your data is not important.

Comment: You say you want to "format the c drive". Do just want to repartition it to set up a dual boot (keep windows and install Ubuntu alongside), or do you want to format it and get rid of Windows?

Comment: I'd recommend keeping Windows 10 just in case you need to do something like updating your BIOS, or running a Windows app that has no Ubuntu counterpart. Install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration (along side of Windows installer choice).

Answer (score -1):

You can do that during the Ubuntu Install.

When it ask you How you'd like to install it.

Select the option that says I'd like to do something else.

On the next screen is the partitions:

- Select the C Drive
- Format it
- Install Ubuntu on the newly formatted drive

**If you DO NOT know what you are doing, you could always unplug the other drives and just wipe and install Ubuntu**

Also check out [GParted](http://gparted.org/)

Comment: There are 3 problems with this answer. First, Ubuntu does not refer to drives or partitions as `C Drive`. Second, Ubuntu needs at least 2 partitions, `/` and `swap`. "Format it" does not explain what mount point or what format type. Third, often D, E and F drives are not separate physical drives, but partitions in a single drive. **They can't be unplugged**.